# How to encrypt password only if it is not empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption

enter code here I am using MD5 for encrypting my password, However, In editing the user profile the user tend not to edit their password. So leaving the password as is. But in my implementation the password is always updated.

```
    Here is the code in my account model.rb
    class Admin::Account < ActiveRecord::Base
      require 'digest/md5'
      acts_as_reader
      before_save :encrypt_password

      def encrypt_password
        self.password = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(password)
      end
    end
```

//**EDIT**
    class Admin::AccountsController < ApplicationController

```
  before_filter :check_login, only: [:new, :index, :edit, :show, :destroy]
  before_action :set_admin_locale, only: [:new, :index, :edit, :show, :destroy,:create,:update]
  layout 'admin_layout'
  # before_action :set_admin_account, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /admin/accounts
  # GET /admin/accounts.json

  def update_user
    @admin_account = Admin::Account.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
    if @admin_account.update(admin_account_params)
      @success = true
      session[:nationality] = @admin_account.nationality
      format.js
    else
      @success = false
      format.js
    end
    end
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_admin_account
    @admin_account = Admin::Account.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def admin_account_params
    gender = "M"
    if params[:admin_account][:gender] == "Female"
      gender = "F"
    end
    if params[:admin_account][:password] != ""
      params.require(:admin_account).permit(:email, :password, :name, :account_type, :student_number, :nationality,:photo,:date_of_birth).merge(:gender => gender)
    else
      params.require(:admin_account).permit(:email, :name, :account_type, :student_number, :nationality,:photo,:date_of_birth).merge(:gender => gender)
    end
  end

  def register_account
    gender = "M"

    if params[:admin_account][:gender] == "Female"
      gender = "F"
    end

    if params[:admin_account][:student_number].present?
      params.require(:admin_account).permit(:email, :password, :name, :password_confirmation, :student_number,:nationality,:photo,:date_of_birth).merge(:account_type => 'Student', :gender => gender)
    else
      params.require(:admin_account).permit(:gender,:email, :password, :name, :password_confirmation,:nationality,:photo,:date_of_birth).merge(:account_type => 'Not Student',:gender => gender)
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

put a condition in your `encrypt_password` method

```
def encrypt_password
   if password.present? and !password.blank?
     self.password = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(password)
   end
end
```

Comment: Sorry for not making myself clear. I tried your implementation and it work if the password column in my table is empty. But I want the model to check if the user inputted the password on my form, then if he/she not inputted then bypass the encryption.

Comment: post your accounts_controller also that will help me to understand.

Comment: I already edited my question with supplied accounts_controller

Comment: why would you bypass the encryption? that would be a flaw.

Comment: Some user would like to update their account but not the password. The user is not required to changed their password everytime they update their account